# Make Keycloak log in JSON format

Tags: logging, jboss, keycloak

How do get [Keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org) 4.5.0.Final to log in JSON format?

I'm running Keycloak in Kubernetes using the [Helm chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/keycloak), which provides hooks for running JBoss CLI scripts (`keycloak.cli.custom`) or shell scripts (`keycloak.preStartScript`).

But I would like to avoid having to customize the Docker image.

Comment: Out of interest, how would you do it if you were to customize the docker image? I am wondering whether there is a way to configure it through the cli alone or if you have to install a wildfly extension

Comment: @RyanDawson Not really sure, but this article describes using a formatter from jboss-logmanager-ext, which would have to be installed before it can be configured through cli: http://wildfly.org/news/2015/07/25/Wildfly-And-ELK/. 
I guess I could copy the jar to the container using an init-container, but that's way more complicated than I'd like.

Comment: Out of interest, did you have much luck with this?

Comment: @RyanDawson From what I found, the Keycloak docker image does not contain a formatter that can produce JSON. I decided to add [Mark Paluch's WildFly JSON Formatter](https://logging.paluch.biz/examples/wildfly-json.html) via an init container and configure the logging subsystem using JBoss CLI similar o what's described [here](http://wildfly.org/news/2015/07/25/Wildfly-And-ELK/)

Answer (score 3):

I'm using keycloak 8.0.1 so this may not apply to your 4.5 version but all I had to do was to supply a jboss cli script to use the json formatter instead of the PATTERN formatter

```
# Undertow HTTP Server Configuration

echo Started configuring Undertow ....

# Create a new log formatter to output json with full stacktrace details
/subsystem=logging/json-formatter=SUMO_FORMATTER:add(pretty-print=false, exception-output-type=detailed-and-formatted, print-details=false)
# Disable the original console output that was in plain text format
/subsystem=logging/console-handler=CONSOLE/:write-attribute(name=enabled,value=false)
# Create a new console logger that uses the new json formatter
/subsystem=logging/console-handler=SUMO_CONSOLE:add(enabled=true, named-formatter=SUMO_FORMATTER)
# Make the root logger use the new console logger
/subsystem=logging/root-logger=ROOT/:write-attribute(name=handlers,value=["SUMO_CONSOLE"])

echo ... Completed configuring Undertow
```

There's some doco on it here

- https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.2/html/configuration_guide/logging_with_jboss_eap#configure_json_log_formatter
- https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.2/html/configuration_guide/reference_material#json_log_formatter_attributes

Answer (score 2):

Following this great [article](https://dev.to/adwaitthattey/building-an-event-listener-spi-plugin-for-keycloak-2044) (which also link to Github), one can achieve JSON logs following these steps:

1. Create a JAVA project which implements Keycloak SPI plugin - This plugin will listen to Keycloakevents and may replace the default logger
2. Modify the code to stringify event objects in JSON format
3. Build the project as a library and place the jar executable file in Keycloak`deployments` folder (please follow the article to get the full details)
4. Go to Keycloakadmin interface, select relevant realm and replace default logger with your logger

Final code may looke something like this:

```
public class MyEventListenerProvider implements EventListenerProvider {

    public MyEventListenerProvider() {
        // use c'tor to init variables / connections / etc. - plugin load hook
        this.jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    }

    ObjectMapper jsonMapper;

   private stringify(Object obj) {
       try {
          return this.jsonMapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
       } catch (Exception ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
          return null;
       }
   }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(Event event) {
        System.out.println(this.stringify(event));
    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(AdminEvent adminEvent, boolean b) {
          System.out.println(this.stringify(adminEvent));
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
       // use close to close connections / reset variables - plugin unload hook
    }
```

This sample is written on the fly (it's partial, sorry if there are compilation errors) and uses Jackson lib as described [here](https://blog.codota.com/how-to-convert-a-java-object-into-a-json-string/)

Comment: Sorry, but I think this is missing the point. Your code is fine for logging Keycloak's Events and AdminEvents, but won't help with making Keycloak format its regular log messages in JSON format (which is what I asked for).

Comment: Just remove the default keycloak logger (in admin dashboard -> your realm -> events -> config) and replace it with your plugin - that way you will ensure that the "default" keycloak logs are in JSON format (section number 4 in my answer)

Comment: Sorry, but I think we're still talking past each other. I don't think your approach would change the regular log message "16:55:52.446 INFO Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9090" from the screenshot in the article you linked to above. What you proposed is an EventListener that logs events, but not a general purpose logger.

Answer (score 0):

(The question asked about 4.5.0, but this might be helpful for more modern versions - e.g. 21.0.2 - as people may come across this through searches etc as I did.)

You can enable JSON logging with an option on startup, as described [here](https://www.keycloak.org/server/logging):

```
bin/kc.[sh|bat] start --log-console-output=json
```